# calling a json array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have an json array of

```
[{
"id": "21390238becde1290",
"chelsea": {
    "homeTeam": "chelsea",
    "sortName": "ches",
    "awayTeam": "Maribor",
    "awayShort": ""
},
"barclays": {
    "id": "21390238becde1290",
    "homeTeam": "barclays",
    "sortName": "barc",
    "awayTeam": "Hull",
    "awayShort": ""
}
}]
```

Controller:

```
footBallApp.controller('TeamInfoEdit',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $translate, carwashService) {

        $rootScope.washTypes;

        $scope.onViewLoaded = function () {
           matchService.getTeamTypes($scope.TypeSelected);
        }

        $scope.TypeSelected = function (response) {
            debugger;
            if (response) {
                $rootScope.teamAvailable = response;
                $scope.localizedTeamName = getLocalizedCollection($scope.teamAvailable);
            }
        }

        // Editing the Team Details.

        $scope.editTeamDetails = function (key) {
            console.log(key._id);

            $rootScope.selectTeam =[]; 
            for(var i=0; i<$scope.teamAvailable.length;i++){
            if($scope.teamAvailable[i]._id== key._id)
            {
                console.log($scope.teamAvailable[i]);
                $scope.selectTeam.push($scope.teamAvailable[i]);
                debugger;
```

And I have assigned the array to `$scope.selectTeam`. When Im trying to call `$scope.selectTeam.chelsea`.Im getting it as `Undefined` in the console. While calling the `json` I'm going wrong but couldn't find it, so how do I call the array correctly. So looking for help in this.

Comment: Can you show the code that is used to assign the *object* (not an array) to the $scope? And also the place you're attempting to read it again.

Comment: its all working here - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/13212/

Comment: If above is your JSON object, the it is incorrect. For more help, please share the code.

Comment: need full code, usage depends on where you use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your array looks like, but try to call:

```
$scope.selectTeam[0].chelsea
```

Answer (score 0):

Array is coming because of uninitialized.
If you initialize $rootScope.teamAvailable = {}; then if response data comes in json format it will overwrite.

Comment: I'm still getting `undefined`